# Трассировка OpenCV в QtCreator

Tags: linux, отладка, opencv, qtcreator, разделяемые-библиотеки

Есть собранный проект с **OpenCV** (**Ubuntu 16.04, OpenCV 3.2**, собирался на месте из исходников в **DEBUG**е через **CMake/make**, все библиотеки/хедеры/исходники имеются), практически пустой, ***imread() + imshow() + waitkey()***, всё компилируется и выполняется. Задача в том, чтобы из **Creator**'а зайти внутрь и протрассировать к.-л. ф-цию модуля **OpenCV** (***imshow***, например, хотя истинной целью являются функции калибровки камер). **F11** не работает, функции выполняются целиком как "чёрные ящики". М.б. дело в **Creator**'е и его способности **отлаживать *shared libraries***, созданные где-то снаружи?

PS. В MSVC есть фича Attach process - как раз для этого, м.б. здесь есть что-то подобное?

Comment: точно ли при запуске под отладчиком используется собранный OpenCV, а не какой-нить системный? и исходники после сборке не двигались ли?

Comment: Исходники не перемещались, OpenCV один-одинёшенек (. Проверено на разных машинах. Creator даже не может по клику на функции скакнуть на её тело, только в хедер.

Comment: этого он и не должен уметь... а вот  при пошаговой отладке `gdb` зайти в неё должен. если нет. то желательно удостовериться `objdump`'ом, что opencv действительно собран с отладочной информацией...

Comment: Для перехода к исходникам оффлайн, видимо, нужно включить их в тот же проект, у меня задача - только трассировка и отладка функций OpenCv.

Comment: Ну, показывает objdump метки, а на некоторых машинах - полностью куски кода, и ничего...

Comment: дык, при пошаговой отладке `step`'ом зайти в функцию на получается?

Comment: Нет, не получается. Проскакивает целиком. Только разве дизассемблером ).

Comment: а при «заходе дизассемблером» имя файла с исходником и номер строки в окне бектрейса отображаются? если нет, то у меня стойкое подозрение, что либа всё же собрана без отладочной информации. В противном случае, если команда `list` отображает исходник, то проблема скорей всего в самом креаторе; иначе — в том что сорцы лежат где-то не там...